# How to use Laravel's ORM to submit the image_id an tag_id to my image_tag table which connects images with tags?

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have a Tag.php model which has hasMany relationship with the Image.php model. I already have a working images and tags tables, however, I am not sure how to make the image_tag table be automatically filled when I upload an image with a certain tag. If I were using vanilla PHP, I would insert the image first, then get its id, get the id of the tag and then make a second insert into the image_tag table. This is my code:

Upload view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="formContainer">
            <form action="{{ route('imageUpload') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input class='contactInput' type="text" name="name" placeholder="Image Name">
                <label for="description">Description</label>
                <input class='contactInput' type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description">
                <label for="description">Tag</label>
                <select class='tagSelect' name='tags'>
                @foreach($tags as $tag)
                    <option value='{{$tag->name}}'>{{$tag->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
                </select>
                <input type="file" name="image">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <button class='contactSubmit' type="submit" name="submit">UPLOAD</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

uploadImage function from my ImagesController:

```
class ImagesController extends Controller
{
    public function uploadImage(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|max:120',
            'description' => 'max:120|nullable',
            'image' => 'required|max:1999'
        ]);

        $name = $request['name'];
        $description = $request['description'];
        $tag = $request['tags'];
        $userId = auth()->user()->id;
        $file = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileName = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore = $fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
        $fileNameToStore = str_replace(' ', '', $fileNameToStore);
        $path = $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/images/uploaded', $fileNameToStore);

        $image = new Image();
        $image->name = $name;
        $image->description = $description;
        $image->user_id = $userId;
        $image->file_name = $fileNameToStore;

        $image->save();

        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are going all wrong.
your relation is Many to Many
so in your Tag model you should do

```
public function images() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Image::class, 'your pivot table name in this case image_tag ','tag_id','image_id');
}
```

and in Image model

```
public function tags() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'your pivot table name in this case image_tag ','image_id','tag_id');
}
```

then you can save an image and attach tags like this

```
$image->tags()->attach($tags)
```

which $tags is an array of ids like [1,2,3,4,5,6]

```
$image = new Image();
$image->name = $name;
$image->description = $description;
$image->user_id = $userId;
$image->file_name = $fileNameToStore;

$image->save();
$image->tags()->attach($tags);
```

hope it helps

Comment: I more or less understand how it works after your explanation, however, I now get a Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name 'image_tag ' (SQL: insert into `image_tag ` (`image_id`, `tag_id`) values (15, 11)). I do have an image_tag table and image_id and tag_id fields which take integers. Any clue as to why this is happening?